Horror/Thriller movie where a girl finds a piece of jewellery near the ocean. People (and animals) start jumping off the cliff-edge
I think it's a fairly new film. The film is about a family going to live in a farm (?) near a cliff/ocean. The little girl finds some kind of jewelry or something in the water when she went to go play, I think later the sheep started to die, they jumped off the cliff. I think at the end, the dad jumps off the cliff with the little girl, and the mom jumps after them so save her daughter. Ugh, I'm so sorry about my description but, I don't know what else, that's all I pretty much remember about the film.
